# PHP array copying error

Tags: php

when I'm trying to copy an array's element to another using php

```
$new=array();
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i+3){
$new[] = $old[$i];
}
```

it is throwing an error `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes)`

I need to copy `old`'s element into `new` by skipping two elements in between (I need 1st, 4th, 7th elements .. skipping 2nd&3rd, 5th&6th, 8th&9th)

suggest me how

**update:solved---sry its typo error...** its silly but i starred @ my code for 15min and not found my typo error...am copying the code, how i rectified

```
$new=array();
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i+=3){
$new[] = $vdo[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo, I believe. Replace `$i+3` with `$i+=3`. You just get into infinite loop and your `$new` array grows out of proportion and memory.

Comment: thanks i'm just wondering, how sad... ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
$new=array();
for($i=0, $j=0;$i<$num;$i+=3, $j++){
$new[$j] = $old[$i];
}
```

Comment: Why introduce variable if you can do without?